# Follow path constraint changes location of object

Tags: animation, node-editor, animation-nodes

I am following a tutorial and added a follow path constraint targeting a bezier circle which changes the location of the object.

[image]

What could I be doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Suggest you go through Polyfjord's tutorial again making sure you haven't missed any steps!

Comment: I tried going through the tutorial again and can't see anything I missed.

Comment: All I can say is that it worked first go for me when I did it a few months ago.

Comment: I will try redoing the whole thing.

Comment: As long as all the objects origins are correct, you should only need to delete the armature and start again from around 19:30 on.

Comment: if you provide your blend file, i will check it out. I succeeded rebuilding Polyfjords tutorial which is very well explained and one of the best in yt in my opinion.